# Would it be unbalanced to allow a non-warforged artificer to use a wand sheath if they make it themselves using one of their infusions?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, balance, house-rules, artificer

One of my players is thinking about going artillerist but they don't have enough hands to hold a shield, an arcane firearm, and a sword. In going down the rabbit hole of animated shields and dropping items I noticed they could craft a wand sheath that would allow them to use a wand hands-free. However they are a forest gnome and wand sheaths require attunement by warforged.

Would it be unbalanced to allow them to use one they made themselves? I am not concerned with the flavour.

Comment: @Zigmata Subjective answers are appropriate for RPG.SE. However, the guide lines for Good Subjective answers are that they should quote relevant experience. For example, Problem Player questions are often highly subjective as to what the “best” answer is. As such, answerers are required to back up their answer with experience of how effective the solution they’ve given was. Theres plenty of articles and [meta] questions that will help you give Good Subjective answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### No, it would not be unbalanced

In my opinion, it would not be unbalanced for several reasons:

- Firstly, most wands require an action to use. This means that they are either going to make an attack with their weapon or with their wand, they can’t do both in the same turn. This quickly curbs any possible issues about them getting multiple attacks per turn, as it isn’t possible according to the Action Economy.
- Secondly, they would be able to achieve a similar thing anyway within the rules. Drawing or stowing a weapon takes an object interaction. It is well within the rules for this character to make an attack with their weapon, use their object interaction to put it away and then, next turn, use their object interaction to draw their wand and their action to use it. All the wand sheath would do is remove the need to expend an object interaction.

So, for these reasons, I feel it would not be unbalanced to allow for the non-warforged character to use a wand sheath.

---

If you felt that it might cause an imbalance, you could say something along the lines of “because your wand sheath is homemade, you need a free hand in order to use it. However, sheathing or unsheathing a wand into the wand sheath does not cost an object interaction”. What this would mean is the player would have to use their object interaction to put their weapon away before they can use the wand. If you wanted to justify the reasoning behind that, look at this image of a retractable dagger which requires a free hand to use:

[image]
Source:https://mobile.twitter.com/assassinscreed/status/855535369009459202

Imagine if that blade was a wand and spun the other way so it was pointing upwards relative to the hand. You could claim this is the reason the homemade wand sheath requires your free hand to use it where as the regular wand sheath design (the one used by the warforged) is significantly different.

Answer (score 7):

At level 14 an artificer gains the Magic Item Savant ability that lets them "ignore all class, race, spell, and level requirements on attuning to or using a magic item".

I feel it's not unbalanced to let a non-warforged character use a wand sheath as the artificer can do it eventually anyways. It's a matter of you're okay with letting them use it when they haven't reached that level yet!

I'm playing a Firbolg artificer, and for the fluff he has a prosthetic arm so that I can eventually have the wand sheath make a bit more sense.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se. Please, take our [tour]. Usually, allowing a character to do something from a higher level earlier *will* imbalance the game. I feel this answer would be improved greatly by backing it up on why *this specific* case will not break the balance. Right now the answer is based on "feels" and "being okay", but that is subjective and doesn't seem to be backed up by experience in the current state of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It becomes immediately apparent that the wand sheath being exclusively for warforged is not a matter of balance, but of flavor when one regards the fact that the item is simply a compartment inside the warforged body.  Just as an arm blade is warforged only for flavor elements, not mechanical ones.  The Warforged race is already balanced with other races without the magic items as 5e was designed to be entirely playable without them.  As for balance, there is no issue.  It is not as though the items are designed to specifically take advantage of unique racial features or limitations.  Certain items do have class limitations for that reason, but most racially limited items have to do with the history and aesthetic of D&D.

This all being said, level 14 artificers do gain the ability to ignore these limitations entirely anyway.  So the question then becomes, does granting this benefit limit the value of that feature.  And without additional limitations, yes. The easiest limitation is to require a prosthetic arm or be a warforged.  This maintains the aesthetic, and the limb can be mitigated later with regeneration later.  Nerfing the wand sheath itself because it is "homemade" would be absurd, because that would require you to do the same for every Replicate Magic Item option.

I have had this come up in the past, and by no means did it significantly improve the non-warforged artificer any more than it did the warforged artificer.  Both gained significant increases to damage for their tier when they became capable of creating the arcane firearm.  Remember that the Artillerist basically has a bonus action burning hands cannon they can mount on their shoulder (can have legs, can move, can be tiny.  there is no reason it cannot ride there), or a temp hp shield, or a force cannon.  Allowing an artificer to have a sword, shield, and a bit extra damage isn't game breaking.

Answer (score -1):

It would not be unbalanced, but it would be a house rule resulting in a buff to the player. Allowing it would be better than the War Caster feat's free somatic usage since the player also gains the benefit of the Arcane Firearm, but it's still insignificant in terms of balance because they can only have one action to either use the Firearm or swing the Sword.

You can have them make do within the rules which imposes some drawbacks. If the player has the Sword out and wants to use the Firearm, they can drop the Sword for free, pull out the Firearm as their object interaction, and then use it for an attack. This will result in them not having the Sword ready for Opportunity Attacks, and they'll have to swap back next turn. If they have the Firearm out they'll need to drop it to draw their Sword. In either case, having their alternate weapon on the floor could present a liability and limit their movement if they intend to pick it up. This is how I handle such cases.

As a halfway measure, you could offer the player a Quick-Sheathing Firearm that lets them draw or sheath the Firearm once per turn as a free action. This would have the benefit of not making them drop items on the floor but still limit their readiness for Opportunity Attacks based on whether they had the Sword or Firearm readied last.

I think it would be reasonably thematic and flavorful for a Gnome Artificer to create either the Quick-Sheathing Firearm or a Wand Sheath for themselves.

Answer (score -2):

Considering artificers, magewrights and the like designed and built the Warforged, its totally within bounds for an artificer to craft themselves something like that. It doesn't really affect your damage output and its awesome for rp.
Rock it.

Answer (score -9):

I dont have enough experience in 5e or DND in general to give you a weighted answer on balance, so I will just state my feelings on this matter.

Given that a Wand Sheath basically allows a user to bypass the 2-items-only limit, and is available to Warforged, I dont think it would hurt balance much if at all to allow another creature to use one.

If you were to consider a limiter for it, perhaps you could rule it to only work with artificial limbs, such as the Prosthetic Limb ,though this would require your player to use 2 attunement slots (though they can eventually attune to 6 items at once).